# Checking the referer of 'path/:id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I have a standard resource:

```
resources :customers
```

On the page "show" (`/customers/:id`) there is a link referring to other customer. When I click on it, how do I check whether or not the referer is `/customers/:id` page? I tried to do this:

```
[1] pry(#<CustomersController>)> URI(request.referer).path
=> "/customers/88" # previous ulr

[2] pry(#<CustomersController>)> customer_path
=> "/customers/98" # current url
```

but it doesn't work. In other words, `:id` in `/customers/:id` always changes, so how can I check whether  `URI(request.referer).path` belongs to `customer_path`?

```
if URI(request.referer).path == ??? #???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, however is far from being pretty. It is however quite flexible and is relaying on generated url helper, so shouldn't break if you decide to change url mappings.

```
if URI(request.referer).path =~ Regexp.new(customer_path(':customer_id').gsub(':customer_id', '\d+'))
```

MUCH, MUCH, BETTER SOLUTION:

Rails application have a method to recognize paths already and returns with controller/action:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(URI(request.referer).path)
#=> {:controller => 'customers', :action => 'show', :id => '88'}
```

You can use it to write a helper method:

```
def is_referer_customer_show_action?
  referer_url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(URI(request.referer).path)
  referer_url[:controller] == 'customers' && referer_url[:action] == 'show'
end
```

Comment: `is_referer_customer_show_action` seems like hard-code. Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need to wrap it into a method if you don't want to. You can just call `recognize_path` method and then check it's controller and action key.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I said that 'customers' and 'show' are hard-coded which is not good.

Comment: @Alex - I think I did. I thought you wanted to know whether referer was some action form some controller. How else do you want to do this without using controller name and action name?

Comment: I don't know, using some abstraction, perhaps.